# Enable PostGIS extension on Ubuntu 14.04.2

Tags: postgis

I have troubles enabling PostGIS extension on Ubuntu 14.04.2 and PostgreSQL 9.3. I have installed the packages with this step by step [procedure](http://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/UsersWikiPostGIS21UbuntuPGSQL93Apt).

PostgreSQL and pgAdminIII seem to be installed properly. I can launch pgAdminIII and the localhost default server exists. I add a new DB and type in `CREATE EXTENSION postgis;`. I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/usr/share/postgresql/9.3/extension/postgis.control": Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
```

Could anyone help?

Comment: Does /usr/share/postgresql/9.3/extension/postgis.control exist? Does it have the correct permissions set, ie, what does ls postgis.control show?

Comment: No it doesn't... I have checked in this directory.

Comment: Does it exist somewhere else? Do you have a previous version of psql running that is looking elsewhere?

Comment: Yes I have a PostgreSQL 9.3 and 9.4 versions in /usr/share/postgresql/. When I run pgAdminIII and execute a SELECT version(); I get the 9.3.9. How could I remove the 9.4 correctly and exhaustively? If the problem comes from that...

Comment: It should not, as both will support CREATE EXTENSION. I thought you might have an 8.x version, which does not. So, where is your postgis.control?

Comment: I can't find this file. I have eventually removed both PostgreSQL versions and started install from beginning. It works now... Many thanks for your help @John Barça!

Comment: Glad it is working. Enjoy.